# Cordless vacumn charger rating calculation

Tags: charger, component-selection

I got a cordless vacuum whose charger got damaged and I found a "close enough" replacement. What could be the new charging performance that I can expect or how can I do a calculation to determine the charging duration?

Original charger rating:
22V
500ma
5 hours

Replacement charger rating:
18V
2000ma
?? hours

Comment: Well, first you need to be sure what battery chemistry you are dealing with. Until you know that, you cannot work out what sort of battery charging protocol you should be using, unless the device has a built-in charger...

Comment: You need to match the voltage first.

Answer (score 1):

Probably "never."  I doubt it is charging at all.

The voltage on the "new" charger is lower than on the old one.

You need to match the voltage of the new charger to the voltage of the original one.

If the voltage is lower than it expects, then the regulating circuit that controls the charging process won't even start.

---

Your vacuum cleaner may have a simple "charge regulator" that is nothing more than a current limiter (like a series resistor.)

It might seem to do something, but will also never fully charge the battery.

Comment: Thank you. I though just a 4v difference wouldnt mean much to it.

The model is a Bosch BBHL21840 18V Cordless Handstick Vacuum Cleaner. Based on that ingo could you make a guess what sort of charging tech it has?

Comment: A relatively "smart" charging system.  It uses lithium ion batteries - those have to be carefully charged to keep them from exploding.  The "charger" you plug into the wall is just a power supply.  The smarts of the charger are built into the vacuum cleaner itself. So, wrong power supply = no charging.